# How can I can I change a Vue component dynamically based on time? By change I mean that one replaces the other like in a carrousel

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

I would like for some widgets that I have in my Vue website to change every n seconds. What is the best way to archive this? By change I mean that one replaces the other like in a carrousel.

Comment: As it stands, the question is way too broad. Basically, you need to adjust the state of application in some way, and view will be repainted accordingly. To go into more details, show more details in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/r48m171wwm) example.

You can change the displayed widget (re: component) by setting an interval and binding [dynamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html).

```
<template>
  <component :is="active"></component>
</template>

<script>
  import ComponentA from "./components/ComponentA";
  import ComponentB from "./components/ComponentB";
  import ComponentC from "./components/ComponentC";

  export default {
    name: "App",
    components: {
      ComponentA,
      ComponentB,
      ComponentC
    },
    data () {
      return {
        rate: 5,
        active: 'component-a',
        interval: null,
        components: ['component-a', 'component-b', 'component-c']
     }
   },
   mounted () {
     this.interval = setInterval(this.rotate.bind(this), this.rate)
   },
   methods: {
     rotate () {
       const index = this.components.findIndex(component => component === this.active)

       this.active = ((index + 1) === this.components.length) ? this.components[0] : this.components[index + 1]
     }
   }
</script>
```